# Adding custom layout xml to adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, configuration, xml

I want to add a custom layout xml file to update `adminhtml`. I have it working now by adding the xml file to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/[module]/custom.xml`. I don't like adding this file to the `default/default` folder however.

Is it possible to add it to `[custom]/[theme]` instead of `default/default` ?

Comment: Means you want to create a new admin theme for this ?

Comment: Is that the way to go? Or is it overkill?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think, there's no problem OR any issue to put `custom.xml` in `default/default`.

As you want to put `custom.xml` in `[custom]/[theme]` (*don't know why*), it's clear that you have to create an admin theme. For this edit `app/etc/local.xml` and put below code in :

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <!-- IF YOU WANT TO CREATE AN ADMIN PACKAGE, UNCOMMENT THIS 
                <package>
                    <name>your_admin_package_name</name>
                </package>
                -->
                <theme>
                    <default>your_admin_theme_name</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

Now you can put your `custom.xml` at `app/design/adminhtml/default/your_admin_theme_name/layout/[module]/custom.xml`.

If you have created an admin package then put `custom.xml` at `app/design/adminhtml/your_admin_package_name/your_admin_theme_name/layout/[module]/custom.xml`

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I would want to do this is just to keep the default magento files seperate from my updates and customizations.

Comment: Yes, as you know, if you update/upgrade Magento, files at `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/[module]/*.*` will NEVER be overwritten. So putting files at `default/default/layout/[module]/` location is not a problem. Thought I provided a solution that will work for you.

Comment: @mlipie: Have you tried this solution ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. I chose to just do it in default/default anyway. I realized there indeed isn't a good reason to make a new theme for this.

Comment: Yes, that's  a good thing to go in `default/default`